# ¿como leer un vector string con espacios en c++?

Tags: c++

hola (program exited with code: -1073741819)
no me apararece ningún error de compilación pero cuando ejecuto y copio la tabla que tengo que convertir a otro formato me aparece el siguiente error
[image: error]
supongo que el error esta en la forma de lectura, no soy bueno con el manejo de caracteres, estaba leyendo con el método cin, pero se detiene hasta que encuentra otro espacio, así que  investigue y use getline, pero ahora ejecuto y me aparece este error, lo que quiero hacer es que tome todo una linea hasta que encuentre salto de linea  como una cadena y guardarlo en un vector de tipo Sting y volver a mostrarlo por pantalla, anexo código.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h> 
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(){
    
    
     int n = 0;
    
    
     cout<<"[+] Ingrese el valor de estudiantes:";
     cin>>n;
    
     std::vector<string> v(n);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    
            getline(cin,v[i]);
    
         }
    
         for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i){
    
            cout<<"[+]"<<v[i]<<'\n';
    
         }
        
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: En la respuesta mencioné que el rango va de 0 a n - 1. O sea `i < n` como lo escribí en el código. ¿Por qué insistes en escribir así el tuyo?

Comment: @Mateo acabo de entender, perdon

Comment: Ah. No te preocupes. Pregunta cuando no quede claro. También sugiero que dejes el código como estaba al comienzo. Ahora está en parte arreglado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que el error esté siendo causado porque las posiciones van de **0** a **n - 1**.

En tu código vas de **0** a **n**.

Si lo haces porque el programa aparentemente toma un elemento menos, lo que sucede es que `cin >> n` deja un salto de línea sin leer. Entonces `getline` lee hasta ese salto de línea.

Solo tienes que consumir el salto de línea para que no moleste. Puedes usar [`cin.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) o [`cin.ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

```
int main() {

    int n = 0;

    cout << "[+] Ingrese el valor de estudiantes:";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(1);

    std::vector<string> v(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        getline(cin, v[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "[+]" << v[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```